# Not responding in Delphi, avoid ProcessMessages and use Threads

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I am using this procedure to execute a Comandline. I have found this piece of code online and it works fine, except a few details. I have read in some forums not to use `ProcessMessages` and put it into a thread.

When I remove the `Application.ProcessMessages` line, then it stops working.
Then if I keep it, while it's executing I get `"Not responding"`. Could you help me in using a thread in this case?

```
procedure ExecAndWait(const CommandLine: string);
var
  StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcessInfo: TProcessInformation;
begin
  FillChar(StartupInfo, SizeOf(StartupInfo), 0);
  StartupInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
  StartupInfo.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
  StartupInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;

  //UniqueString(CommandLine);

  if CreateProcess(nil, PChar(CommandLine), nil, nil, False,
    0, nil, nil, StartupInfo, ProcessInfo) then
  begin
    while WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, 10) > 0 do
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
  end
  else
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
end.

procedure BuildThread;
var
  myThread: TThread;

begin
  // Create an anonymous thread that calls a method and passes in
  // the fetchURL to that method.
  myThread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      ExecAndWait();
    end);
end;
```

I added this:

```
procedure RunThread(const CommandLine: string);
var
  myThread: TThread;        
begin
  myThread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      ExecAndWait(CommandLine);
    end). Start;
end;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, basically I want to know how to prevent the "Not responding" from showing. I read online and they suggest to put the CreateProcess into a thread

Comment: Create a thread to wait on the process handle. When it is signaled, notify the UI thread.

Comment: Since you haven't created working threads yet, start with simple examples from help, call your `ExecAndWait` from `Execute` method (or anonymous thread function). Seems you don't need to interact with GUI, so synchronization stuff is not needed

Comment: @MBo thank you for your answer. Delphi is not my language of choice, I have a small project I need to work in it because otherwise I would never dive into it. Since I have never used threads, and if you are a beginner like me, if you try to google you will see there is no simple example. I know what I am trying to do is fairly simple, but I just don't know how to insert a thread. I am not asking for you to do what I need, I would only appreciate if you could show me a simple example.

Comment: @MBo , This is what I am trying to go I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190872/which-is-the-correct-way-to-wait-for-a-thread-finalization-and-keep-my-applicati

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34890222/createanonymousthread-with-parameters

Comment: @MBo thanks, I modified the question. I tried it but it doesn't solve my issue. While it runs (because the procedure may take a few minutes) I get "Not responding" message.

Comment: You are creating an anonymous thread, but forgot to start it.

Comment: @MBo I debugged it and the ExecAndWait never gets executed..., am I missing something?

Comment: @LURD some help on starting it?

Comment: `myThread.Start;`

Comment: @LURD should there also be a myThread.End?

Comment: No, The thread will self destruct when ready. Please slow down and read up on documentation and some examples.

Comment: @LURD CANNOT CALL START ON A RUNNING OR SUSPENDED THREAD

Comment: An anonymous thread should not be reporting this error. You also shouldn't keep a reference to an anonymous thread - that's why it's anonymous. You should close up the call to `CreateAnonymousThread` with `.Start;` `TThread.CreateAnonymousThread( ... ).Start;` You also should not be using `Application.ProcessMessages`, *especially* from within the thread. That breaks the VCL thread safety, or lack thereof rather.

Comment: @JerryDodge thank you. If I do that, then I get the error message: Incompatible types: 'TThread' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'

Comment: That sounds very bizarre - I don't know what to say without seeing your new code. `TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      ExecAndWait(CommandLine);
    end).Start;` That should be *all* the code you need. Don't declare a variable for the thread, don't read the result of `CreateAnonymousThread`, there's no need to.

Comment: If I may, what's the reason to wait for a process inside of a thread when you're not doing anything once it's finished? Do you really need to wait for the process to end? If so, your thread will need some sort of callback to capture the completion. If not, then why wait for it at all in the first place? A simple `ShellExecuteEx` should be all you need in that case.

Comment: @JerryDodge When I do ShellExecute the cmd window opens up, so this is a nice way to not display it. Anyways I do need to wait for it to end because it's a process that can take up to 10 min

Comment: Then use `SW_HIDE`...

Comment: @JerryDodge well, i keep getting the Not responding window and that's really boring, if I switch to ShellExecute..

Comment: Then I highly suggest opening up another question on that subject. If you really don't need to wait for it to finish, then everything you're doing here is a big waste.

Comment: Frankly that was my main concern, to avoid the Not responding

Comment: You shouldn't get Not Responding, when it's done correctly. Most of the time, applications are launched blindly without waiting for completion. It's not every day that one wishes to wait for a process to end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anonymous threads are not meant to be referenced. You should not attempt to keep a local variable referencing your thread. Instead, you should directly call `Start` in-line with the call to `CreateAnonymousThread`...

```
procedure RunThread(const CommandLine: string);       
begin
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      ExecAndWait(CommandLine);
    end).Start;
end;
```

In addition, you should *not* be using `Application.ProcessMessages`, *especially* from within a thread. `Application` is part of the VCL, which is not thread-safe, and thus breaks the VCL multi-threading safety rules. And even if that weren't the case, it's still useless since it's only intended for the main UI thread.